# Automatically copy cell 'y' to cell 'x' if cell 'y' is larger than cell 'x'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title explains, I need to create a solution (I'm thinking most likely a script) so if the value in B1 (this cell has a SUM function) is larger than A1 (fixed integer) then the value shown in B1 will be copied across to A1.

If B1 is smaller than A1, then A1 would remain changed.

This will be used in calculating a stock trading balance all time high. A1 represents the all time high and B1 represents the current balance.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: NOTE: There is a list of balances, so B1 needs to copy to A1, B2 to A2, B3 to A3 etc etc. It is basically copying column B to column A on that row

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement this feature using Google Apps Script. In order to do so, from your sheets document go to Tools>Script editor. There, copy & paste the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('YOUR_SHEET_NAME');
  var nRows = sheet.getDataRange().getHeight();
  var values = sheet.getRange(1, 1, nRows, 2).getValues();

  for (var i=1; i<nRows; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] == "") break;
    if (values[i][0] < values[i][1]) values[i][0] = values[i][1];
  }

  sheet.getRange(1, 1, nRows, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

Adapt the variables as you need (i.e. replace `YOUR_SHEET_NAME`). Now, save the document, click the "Select function" drop-down and select `myFunction`. Click the "play" button. Now the transformation you suggested should be applied.

Finally, in order to understand what is going on, I suggest you check out the following links:

- [Google Apps Script overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).
- [Apps Script Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range).

### EDIT

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var nRows = sheet.getDataRange().getHeight();
  var valuesA = sheet.getRange(2, 1, nRows, 1).getValues();
  var valuesB = sheet.getRange(2, 2, nRows, 1).getValues();
  var valuesE = sheet.getRange(2, 5, nRows, 1).getValues();
  var valuesF = sheet.getRange(2, 6, nRows, 1).getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<nRows; i++) {
    var valueA = valuesA[i][0];
    var valueB = valuesB[i][0];

    if (valueA == "") break;
    if (valueA <= valueB) {
      var formula = Utilities.formatString('=SUM(E%s, F%s)', i+2, i+2);
      sheet.getRange(i+2, 1).setFormula(formula);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have set up a test doc, but cannot get this to work: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1441t3zDjVWeB0I4FqImb8v9TbVu32eACwJAJd07p5VM/edit?usp=sharing The script has been installed, with changes made to the variables as instructed. Can you let me know where I am going wrong. 

Finally, in the cases where a value in B is less than 0, how'd I get this to show 0 in A (0 in the minimum value that can be in A).

Comment: @Dan thanks for pointing that out. I edited my code so it starts at the second row, thus skipping the headers. It should work now. Kindly note that your sheet does NOT have any data in column A. When the script finds an empty cell in column A, it halts execution.

Comment: Thanks. I have tested and wrote a few comments on the sheet.

Comment: I have found a solution to make this fit my requirement other than one thing. When the script is triggered, it overwrites the SUM function shown in col B and makes this a fixed integer rather than a live calculation. How can this script be used but not overwrite the content of Col B?

Comment: @Dan The function you are most likely using (`setValue()` or `setValues()`) only sets a value into the cell, no *formula* will be placed in it. If what you want is the latter, you will have to build a formula using string concatenation and place it using [`setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: So the final line of code in the script would read:   sheet.getRange(1, 1, nRows, 2).setFormula("= E" +i+ "+F" +i+); if I wanted to add columns E and F together for example? I tried this and it stated syntax error. I'm going to apologise for my extreme lack of knowledge here lol - I'm new to scripts. Could you advise on necessary coding changes to SUM columns E and F?

Comment: Hey @Dan, the formula inserted would have to be like the ones you would insert into sheets. Namely, the first cell would have `=SUM(E1, F1)`, the second one `=SUM(E2, F2)`, and so on. You can do this using string concatenation as you just described, along with a for-loop.

Comment: Hey @carlesgg97 I was struggling to understand what the script was performing enough to make changes, so I found a few tutorials and adapted the coding and slightly rebuilt so I could understand how the script was working. On https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1441t3zDjVWeB0I4FqImb8v9TbVu32eACwJAJd07p5VM/edit?usp=sharing I believe I now have the setFormula working correctly (I couldn't find any information about for-loop's and how to integrate), but I cannot work out how to apply your if rules to the adapted script so the script functions as intended and copy larger values to Col A.

Comment: Could you help finish that part off for me so that the setFormula values in B copy to A if they are larger to the preexisting number in A. Thanks

Comment: @Dan Please try the code I just added into the edited answer and kindly let me know if that's what you expected. Cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203039/discussion-between-dan-and-carlesgg97).